# Class not registered

Tags: c++, com, visual-studio-2005

I'm working through "Developer's Workshop to COM and ATL 3.0" by Andrew W. Troelsen.

I'm trying to implement the lab in Chapter 3.

It shows you how to build a COM client to connect to an inprocess COM server that was developed in an earlier lab.

When I run the client, I receive the error "Class not registered" when calling 'CoGetClassObject'.

Here is a snippet of code:

```
// Get the class factory pointer of CoCar.
hr = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_CoCar, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void**)&pCF);

if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    // Make a CoCar & get ICreateCar
    hr = pCF->CreateInstance(NULL, IID_ICreateCar, (void**)&pICreateCar);
    pCF->Release();
}
else
{
    char buff[100];
    BOOL bRet = FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, hr, 0, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
    std::cout << buff << std::endl;
}
```

I have tried to register the class by merging the following .reg file with the system registry:

```
REGEDIT
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CarInProcServer.CoCar\CLSID = {EFC76CF8-71B8-477b-890A-1233BD9177CB}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EFC76CF8-71B8-477b-890A-1233BD9177CB} = CarInProcServer.CoCar
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EFC76CF8-71B8-477b-890A-1233BD9177CB}
\InprocServer32 = C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CarInProcServer\release\CarInProcServer.dll
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but here is my .def file:

```
LIBRARY "CarInProcServer"
EXPORTS
DllGetClassObject   @1  PRIVATE
DllCanUnloadNow     @2  PRIVATE
```

NB: I'm using Windows 7

Can anyone help?

Thanks

---

Got it!

I manually added:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID{EFC76CF8-71B8-477b-890A-1233BD9177CB}
\InprocServer32 = "C:\Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CarInProcServer\release\CarInProcServer.dll"

to the registry.

It seems merging the .reg file with this entry in it did not work. Thanks to Ken White for his help. (and others who suggested solutions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a command prompt, change to your DLL's folder, and run regsvr32.exe:

```
cd \Users\Steven\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Projects\CarInProcServer\release 
regsvr32 CarInProcServer.dll
```

Comment: I tried this, with no luck. I think the author intends for this reg file to be used instead of regsvr32 and DllRegisterServer() According to the book: "We will write our own registry scripts (REG file), which can be used to merge our server information into the registry automatically, bypassing the need to code DllRegisterServer() by hand.

Comment: Steven, don't understand why you'd want to bypass DllRegisterServer, unless this is just an early example just to get things rolling...

Comment: The problem may be a rights issue on Vista or Win7. I notice that your reg file is writing to HKCR; is this by chance Win7 64 bit? If so, that hive is virtualized for 32-bit apps (and DLLs). Search SO for "WOW_64 registry", and you should find some posts on how to resolve this issue. HKCR isn't writable for a standard (non-admin) user on either Vista or Win7, either; have you imported the reg file while running under an Administrator's account?

Comment: Sounds like the settings have merged correctly into the registry, though - see his comment below @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785028/class-not-registered/1785520#1785520

Comment: @bacar: That comment must have been posted right after mine above. It still could be the result of virtualization, though. Never got an answer about the Admin account, or whether or not it's a 32-bit DLL on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Regarding my comment about virtualization, the following might help (it's the first answer to the original question): https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=28468&tstart=0

Comment: It was a 32bit DLL on 64 bit Windows btw.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try registering the COM server with regsvr32.exe?

Answer (score 0):

Is the value of CLSID_CoCar equal to the value in your reg file? ({EFC76CF8-71B8-477b-890A-1233BD9177CB}), or have they been regenerated to different values?

If so, have you checked that these values have been correctly merged into your registry?

Have you called CoInitialize?

Comment: I've checked, and the GUIDs match in the server, and in the registry.

I called 'CoInitialize(NULL);' in the client at the start of main.